# call to authenticated rest web service fails in case of post method spring boot

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-boot

I'm trying to consume a rest web service which is **authenticated** in spring boot application where the Httpmethod is POST,

Below I would like to show how all set up work to consume authenticated web service for HttpMethod.GET and then what changes I try to consume same authenticated web service for HttpMethod.POST and  throws 401 Unauthorized ERROR,

RestTemplateFactory to get restTemplte,

```
   public class RestTemplateFactory implements FactoryBean<RestTemplate>, InitializingBean {

        @Autowired
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

        public RestTemplate getObject() {
            return restTemplate;
        }
        public Class<RestTemplate> getObjectType() {
            return RestTemplate.class;
        }
        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return true;
        }

        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 9090, "http");
            restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
                    new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuth(host));
        }
    }
```

For basic authentication,

```
public class HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuth extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {

        HttpHost host;

        public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuth(HttpHost host) {
            super();
            this.host = host;
        }

        protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
            return createHttpContext();
        }

        private HttpContext createHttpContext() {
            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();

            BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
            authCache.put(host, basicAuth);

            BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
            localcontext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
            return localcontext;
        }
    }
```

Calling a authenticated web service for HttpMethod.Get method,

```
 public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> consumeRestApi(SomeRequest request) throws InvalidDataException {
        ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> responseEntity = null;
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateFactory.getRestTemplate();
            restTemplate
                    .getInterceptors()
                    .add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(username, pwd));

            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:9090/sendMail?phone=60598745&email=abc@gmail.com", HttpMethod.GET, null, SomeResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Exception handing...
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

And I do have dummy server running at localhost, with HttpMethod.Get and this is the authenticated service I'm trying to consume in above set up,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendMail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> sendmail(@RequestParam String phone, @RequestParam String email){

    SomeResponse response = SomeResponse.builder()
            .id("101")
            .type("formdata")
            .fieldValues(getFieldValues(phone,email))
            .build();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

When its a HttpMethod.GET method it works perfectly fine with all the set up mentioned above,

Now, I want to change the same web service to be consumed, to accept a HttpMethod.POST

So below are the changes I tried out but it throw back an error of 401 i.e. Unauthorized error

The changes I try for post method,

By keeping the `RestTemplateFactory` and `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuth` same

I first change, the rest api on dummy server to accept request with POST so,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendMail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> sendmail(@RequestParam String phone, @RequestParam String email){
// Same as above 
}
```

Next change is calling method with method post,

```
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> consumeRestApi(SomeRequest request) throws InvalidDataException {
            ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> responseEntity = null;
            try {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateFactory.getRestTemplate();
                restTemplate
                        .getInterceptors()
                        .add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(username, pwd));

                            SomeResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9090/sendMail?phone=60598745&email=abc@gmail.com",request, SomeResponse.class);

            } catch (Exception e) {
               // Exception handling....
                }
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<SomeResponse>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
```

Does anyone has any suggestion where I'm going wrong with this,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, which version? How have you secured the other endpoint.

Comment: I'm using spring boot version 1.5 and other endpoint in dummy server securing it by adding spring-boot-starter-security

Comment: First ditch your `RestTemplateFactory` and `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuth` and use the `RestTemplateBuilder.basicAuthentication(username, pwd).build()` to create the `RestTemplate`. The `RestTemplate` is thread safe so you only need to create it once and reuse afterwards. Then try again. Feels like you are making it too complex. Have you done any configuration on the server for security or relying on the defaults?

Comment: Ok I will try this, the only configuration is setting up username and password nothing much

Comment: @M.Deinum its does work with  RestTemplateBuilder and removed RestTemplateFactory  and other class  as well . Thank you very for such a simplest solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue lies in your way of creating and configuring the [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). Spring Boot provides the [`RestTemplateBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html) to construct a `RestTemplate` and it has builder methods to do additional configuration.

In addition the `RestTemplate` is thread safe so instead of re-recreating it to use it you can reuse the created instance. That being said your calling class can be refactored to something like this

```
public class EndpointTester {

  private final RestTemplate rest;

  public EndpointTester(RestTemplateBuilder rtb, String username, String pwd) {
    this.rest = rtb.basicAuthorization(username, pwd).build();
  }

  public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> consumeRestApi(SomeRequest request) throws InvalidDataException {
        ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> responseEntity = null;
        try {             
            responseEntity = rest.postForEntity("http://localhost:9090/sendMail?phone=60598745&email=abc@gmail.com", null, SomeResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Exception handing...
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

This way you don't need your `RestTemplateFactory` and `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuth` which simplifies your configuration and code.

Comment: in my application @Bean
    public RestTemplate rest() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    } has been used in AppConfiguration file, can I use this object of RestTemplate in my case any idea

Comment: You would need to configure basic auth then. You can use the `RestTemplateBuilder` there to do the same and inject the `RestTemplate`. Both cases would work.